# Is it possible to remove an eventListener temporarily (i.e. until a function has been executed)

Tags: actionscript-3, addeventlistener

I am doing actionscript 3 at the moment and was wondering if it was possible to remove and eventListner temporarily. I know of removeEventListener, however, that removes the eventListener completely and i cannot click the button again.

If you want some more details, here the exact problem. I have function that when a button is pressed, an object appears. In  the function which makes this object there is an eventListener which leads to a function which allows the user to press that object. When you press that object it disappear and the button will animate. However, since the original eventListener still exists, you can press the object while in motion and create a new object. So to the point: What i want to do is disable the eventListener while the button is moving, and reactivate it when it stops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to simply use a flag which tells the function if the animation is complete or not. Here's an example of what I'm talking about using `TweenLite` as tween library:

```
public class CreateButton extends Sprite{
        private var animating:Boolean = false;

        public function CreateButton(){
            this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick, false, 0, true);
        }

        private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void{
            if(this.animating == false){
                // Trigger creation functionality
                TweenLite.to(this, 0.5, {/* Parameters for the actual animation */ onComplete:animationComplete});      
                this.animating = true;
            }
        }

        private function animationComplete():void{
            this.animating = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would I put this directly into my code or would I make a own Actionscript file and import it?

Comment: If I were you I would put this in a separate file and import it instead of implementing just the functions in your code. That way you can reuse the class and it's functionality later on.

Answer (score 0):

It is best practice to remove the listener if it's functionality is to be disabled. You could however set the .mouseEnabled to false if you want to disable it's click functionality without removing the listener.